# Remote shutting down computer over WiFi with cmd

Tags: windows, cmd, wifi, remote-access, shutdown

## Remote shutting down Windows computer with cmd. Possible?

**I have searched over the internet**, and I have found many solutions for this problem,

### BUT

**No one has worked.** I don't have got the password for the other computer, or permission to shutdown it, I get everytime: **Access denied. (5)** So my quetions are:

- Is there any software tool to do that?
- Is it possible at all?
- Can I make it in Windows on both computers?

Not exactly needed cmd, but must be shutted down by remotely, without installing any software on the second computer.

***Many thanks for help***

Comment: Does it really need to be CMD? Are you owning both computers? You could simply install TM-viewer and then  shutdown it normally.

Comment: Not exactly needed cmd, but must be shutted down by remotely, without installing any software on the second computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for you.

```
RUN secpol.msc in CMD (on the computer u want to enable the remote shutdown)
```

Go to Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment and search for "**Force shutdown from a remote system**"

Double click it and then "**Add User or Group...**" and type "**Everyone**" and then add it.

This SHOULD work! I've set this configuration on my computer and then executed this command on my brother's PC while we are on the same LAN network and i've got the shutdown message AND the computer did restart.

**shutdown -m \\mypcname -r -c "this pc will shutdown in 60 secs" -t 60**

Be sure that u can see the computer u want to shutdown trought **net view**. But u already see it, because u are getting the **Access denied. (5)**.

Report back to the question if it works!

Kind Regards

Comment: Good solution, but I want to shut down the computer without changing any settings on it.

Comment: I'm afraid there will be no other way, because as you already know, the Windows 7 and newer operation system have many security settings enabled to keep the user safe. Also the UAC control and all other things.. If you would like a different solution, i advise you to go ask Microsoft directly what you can do here. 

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Look at:
http://www.wikihow.com/Do-a-Remote-Shutdown-for-a-PC-on-a-LAN
quote:
"At your local command prompt type in shutdown -m \computername, replacing "computername" with the name of the computer you wish to shutdown or the computer's IP address."

Or from within a remote session:
shutdown /s /t 0

(meaning: shut down in 0 seconds)

Comment: U are not specifying anywhere a remote IP or computer name

Comment: It isn't **remote** shutdown, but **local**.

Comment: @Recon: Thanks for the comment, I have improved my answer

Answer (score 0):

- Open cmd
- Write `net view`
- Find the computer you want to kick form your wifi or turn off
- Write `ping ex: USER`
- Find ip address
- Write `shutdown -I`